# How to knows where TextWidget will wrap?

Tags: flutter

When using `Text` widget with big strings, it happens that the displayed text is splitted on 2 or more lines.

My question is simple : How to know the exact character where a string is divided ?

I've digged inside `Text` code. Up to `dart:ui`'s `Paragraph`. But I haven't found anything usable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the text in flutter is painted on canvas using a [TextPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html) which computes the layout size during runtime with the box constrains of its parent class. If you already know the available space, you can compute the layout width of the text and compare it with the available width to know where the text would break.

You can computer the width of the text with `TextPainter` like:

```
final TextPainter paint = new TextPainter(
  text: new TextSpan(
    text: "Hello World",
  ),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
);
paint.layout();
debugPrint(paint.width.toString());
```

---

You can also do it with `CustomPainter` like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  String text = "Hello World";

  void textShownOnUI(int size){
    debugPrint(text.substring(0,size));
  }

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Example",
    home: new Container(
      width: 100.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(175.0),
      child: new CustomPaint(
        painter: new MyTextWidget(
          text: text,
          style: new TextStyle(),
          notifySize: textShownOnUI
        ),
        child: new Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyTextWidget extends CustomPainter {

  Function notifySize;

  String text;

  TextStyle style;

  TextDirection direction;

  MyTextWidget({this.text,this.notifySize,this.style,this.direction});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
    debugPrint(size.width.toString());
    final TextPainter _painterWithConstrains = new TextPainter(
      text: new TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style
      ),
      textDirection: direction??TextDirection.ltr
    );
    String _willBeShownOnUI = text;
    int _size = text.length;
    TextPainter _temp = new TextPainter(
        text: new TextSpan(
            text: _willBeShownOnUI,
            style: style
        ),
        textDirection: direction??TextDirection.ltr
    );
    _painterWithConstrains.layout(maxWidth: size.width);
    _temp.layout();
    while(_temp.width > _painterWithConstrains.width && _size != 0){
      debugPrint(_temp.width.toString()+"  "+ _size.toString());
      _willBeShownOnUI = _willBeShownOnUI.substring(0, --_size);
      _temp = new TextPainter(
          text: new TextSpan(
              text: _willBeShownOnUI,
              style: style
          ),
          textDirection: direction??TextDirection.ltr
      );
      _temp.layout();
    }
    _size = _willBeShownOnUI.split(" ")[0].length; // Get complete words that will be shown
    Function.apply(notifySize,<int>[_size]);
    _painterWithConstrains.paint(canvas, Offset.zero);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. But this isn't what I need. I don't want to know the dimensions of the final result ; but instead where the string is cut in 2.

This is to potentially extract the second line, and display it on another widget.

Comment: That is what compute the layout by slicing the text until the computed layout and available spaces match.

Comment: But that part is inside `dart:ui` written in c++. Hence the question : How can I access it ?

Comment: You cannot directly find it I suppose, instead you can wrap a text in a container of known width.

Comment: That doesn't fit my use-case at all sadly

Comment: Then you need to implement your own custom painter that paints your text and notifies the size where the text breaks. I edited my answer to implement the same.